# Can't add Java ME SDK Plugins properly

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-8

I'm complete newbie to java and I'm trying to make a java mobile application using NetBeans. I installed jdk-8u25-nb-8_0_2-windows-x64.exe

Then I installed oracle-jmesdk-8-1-rr-win-bin.exe

Then I uzipped oracle-jmesdk-8-1-rr-nb-plugins.zip to C:

When I try to add the plugins, I'm getting a warning: Unable to connect to the Java ME SDK Plugins because of C

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

If I ignore this warning and check "Installed" tab, I can't find Java ME. I have several log files: [messages.log](http://sudrap.org/paste/text/499452/) [messages.log.1](http://sudrap.org/paste/text/499455/) [messages.log.2](http://sudrap.org/paste/text/499456/)

How can I activate Java ME SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove one "/" at the beginning of the URL.

```
file:/C:/oracle-jmesdk-8-1-rr-nb-plugins/updates.xml
```

**Caution:** Yes, this sounds strange for an URL, but I think it is a bug in Netbeans (or there is something special with these "file" URI)